# Porque me aparece este mensaje en el símbolo del sistema y luego se cierra sola cuando quiero ejecutar java?

Tags: java, java-8, instalacion, ejecutar

Aclaro que soy nueva en esto de la programación, volví a instalar java porque me compre un a nueva compu (tiene windows 10), se instalo correctamente y todo, pero cuando quiero ejecutar java me sale este mensaje y luego se cierra sola en segundos, alguien me puede ayudar por favor? busque, investigue y busque tutoriales pero simplemente me sigue apareciendo el mismo mensaje y se cierra solo en segundos, alguien podría ayudarme por favor?

---

```
Sintaxis: java [-options] class [args...]
(para ejecutar una clase)
o java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
(para ejecutar un archivo jar)
donde las opciones incluyen:
-d32 usar un modelo de datos de 32 bits, si está disponible
-d64 usar un modelo de datos de 64 bits, si está disponible
-server para seleccionar la VM "server"
La VM por defecto es server.

-cp
-classpath
Lista separada por ; de directorios, archivos JAR
y archivos ZIP para buscar archivos de clase.
-D=
definir una propiedad del sistema
-verbose:[class|gc|jni]
activar la salida verbose
-version imprimir la versión del producto y salir
-version:
es necesario que se ejecute la versión especificada
-showversion imprimir la versión del producto y continuar
-jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
incluir/excluir JRE privados de usuario en la búsqueda de versión
-? -help imprimir este mensaje de ayuda
-X imprimir la ayuda sobre las opciones que no sean estándar
-ea[:...|:]
-enableassertions[:...|:]
activar afirmaciones con la granularidad especificada
-da[:...|:]
-disableassertions[:...|:]
desactivar afirmaciones con la granularidad especificada
-esa | -enablesystemassertions
activar afirmaciones del sistema
-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
desactivar afirmaciones del sistema
-agentlib:[=]
cargar la biblioteca de agente nativa , como -agentlib:hprof
véase también -agentlib:jdwp=help y -agentlib:hprof=help
-agentpath:[=]
cargar biblioteca de agente nativa con el nombre de la ruta de acceso completa
-javaagent:[=]
cargar agente de lenguaje de programación Java, véase java.lang.instrument
-splash:
mostrar una pantalla de presentación con la imagen especificada
```

Answer (score 0):

No se si sea lo que estas buscando, pero hace unos años me paso lo mismo, lo que hice fue en el Path donde se copia el BIN de JDK de las variables del sistema, lo puse hasta arriba como primero, después reinicie mi maquina y finalmente volví abrir CMD y al poner JAVAC, me salió todo lo de java al igual que ya pude compilar mis programas
Puede ser por eso
Si no.
Instala otra versión de JDK, ya sea mas antigua o mas reciente igual probe eso en ciertos casos y me funciono, espero te sirva
Saludos cordiales...

Comment: Aun no puedo usar el simbolo del sistema (se sigue cerrando solo) pero los programas corren bien en netbeans, igual gracias por las ayuda